# Using drush when database and web server are separate

Tags: drush

I am having trouble using drush on server setups where the web (111.11.11.1) and database (222.22.22.2) servers are separate.

```
drush sql-connect
```

gives me the correct output of

```
mysql --user=mysite_user --password=abcdef12345 --database=mysite --host=222.22.22.2
```

If i type this into the console of the web server it connects me to the mysql on the database server correctly, however...

Running

```
drush cc all --debug
```

results in the following messages

```
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_j4KBOf --database=mysite --host=222.22.22.2 --silent  < /tmp/drush_xpMPoI
  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'111.11.11.1' (using password: YES)
```

It looks like drush is trying to connect using a different set of credentials and failing, i cannot find any my.conf where db credentials are hardcoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user name is taken from root's `.my.cnf` file (normally located in `/root/.my.cnf`. Either remove the user line from that file, or run Drush as another user than root (which might not have a `.my.cnf` file.)

Added: The relevant part of the MySQL documentation:

> If multiple instances of a given option are found, the last instance
>   takes precedence, with one exception: For mysqld, the first instance
>   of the `--user` option is used as a security precaution, to prevent a
>   user specified in an option file from being overridden on the command
>   line.